# Make a repeating animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, infinite-loop

I'm trying to make a repeating animation using jQuery. I used a `while` loop with the condition set to `true`, but I think the browser doesn't like it.

What is the way to do this properly?

http://jsfiddle.net/8cV2R/2/

```
$('.test').click(function () {
    while (true) {
        $(this).hide(1000);
        $(this).show(1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: With a CSS animation, probably! But failing that, you’ll need to use the [callback parameter](http://api.jquery.com/show) and run your next animation in there.

Comment: *"but I think the browser doesn't like it."* You sir made my day, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to write a function that has itself as a callback. That's how you loop a function.

http://jsfiddle.net/8cV2R/8

```
$('.test').click(fadeIt);

function fadeIt() {
    $('.test').hide(1000, function() {
        $('.test').show(1000, fadeIt);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be enough :

```
$('.test').click(doMe);

function doMe(){
    $(this).hide(1000).show(1000, doMe);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8cV2R/7/

jQuery queue animation for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function h() { $(this).hide(1000, s); };
function s() { $(this).show(1000, h); };
$('.test').click(h);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8cV2R/5/)**

Or, without the width/height animation that hide/show creates when specifying a duration so you get more of a blink effect: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/JZu6z/)**